# convert the encoding of many files?

Tags: windows, character-encoding

**I have 2000 files encoded in windows-1256. i want to convert their encoding to UTF-8 (all in once)**

can notepad++ do something like this?

Comment: You'd better use utils created specially for that, like `iconv`.

Comment: please tell us your operation system

Comment: Just do it with a Python or Perl script and a `glob`

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. In case of someone needs it:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ../converted
for x in `ls *`
   do iconv -f Windows-1256 -t UTF-8 $x > ../converted/$x
done
```

Note: this is for UNIX systems, in case of Windows you can use Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked at a place where some files where incorrectly downloaded in UTF-8 instead of Windows-1252.
I have created a batch file that contains the command to iconv and got it scheduled to every 30 seconds. Unfortunately I can not show you the details since I no longer have access to it.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Hope this will help you.